# Getting pads from gstreamer element gives error on gstreamer-java for 1.x

Tags: java, gstreamer, java-gstreamer

I was trying to run this java code from https://opencast.jira.com/secure/attachment/10077/MultipleSinks.java with [gstreamer-java 1.x](https://github.com/gstreamer-java/gst1-java-core)

```
public static void printPipeline(Pipeline p) {

    List<Element> elements = p.getElements();

    if (elements.size() > 0) {
        Iterator<Element> elemiter = elements.iterator();
        Element e = null;
        while (elemiter.hasNext()) {
            e = (Element) elemiter.next();

            List<Pad> pads = e.getPads();

            if (pads.size() > 0) {
                Iterator<Pad> paditer = pads.iterator();
                Pad pad = null;
                while (paditer.hasNext()) {
                    pad = (Pad) paditer.next();
                    System.out.print(e + " " + pad.getDirection()); 
                    System.out.println("\t" + pad.getCaps());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`p.getElements()` in the above code gives me:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed this is a bug in gstreamer binding. I filed it on gstreamer-java on https://github.com/gstreamer-java/gst1-java-core/issues.